# In an HTML Saved as xls; how to achieve ALT+Enter Equivalent in html(new line inside a cell)

Tags: html, excel

Hi I have legacy implementation of the spreadsheet import from a gridview and it is as follows
Html representation of the DataTable result set is written onto the HttpResponse stream with content-disposition header set to an xls file (i.e content-disposition=attachment; filename=abcd.xls)

The html tables will intern becomes spreadsheet table. I have a certain set of data in the following format

```html
<table style="border: 1x solid black;">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Items</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
      </ul> 
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item2</li> 
      </ul> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I was expecting spreadsheet to show 2 rows with Items Column showing un-ordered list inside cell. Instead the excel shows up 5 rows (3 rows for Name A and 2 rows for Name B).

In a normal spreadsheet cell we can use ALT+Enter keyword to add new lines inside a cell, Is there a html encode character that tells the xls file to mimic the ALT+Enter action?

I had tried `<br/>`, Line feed character 10 and Carriage Return 13 with no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<td>
    item 1<br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />
    item 2<br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />
    item 3
</td>
```