# Exporting an html table into excel. Styling a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, excel

I'm building a very robust exporter for HTML tables. I'm noticing that having multiple `<div>` or any other tag inside a `<td>` element will stretch it into a stacked row. They need to be this way because it allows for a dynamic row. The header for the row must stretch dynamically based on my data, however I cannot seem to manipulate the style at all.

This is the way that cell is structured in html

```
<td>
    <div>Test A</div>
    <div>Test A</div>
    <div>Test A</div>
</td>
```

I can add styles to the `td` element and get them to show up, but of course it will show up for all of the cells. I don't want that. I need to be able to manipulate those div cells.

This is what it looks like now
[image]

I just need to figure out if there is a tag that excel understands that will allow me to add styling to it. I have tried...

- nesting `td` tags in it. I can style them, but the cells are no longer in the right place
- using 'span' and 'p' classes. These do the same as `div` of course because excel doesn't understand them.

My code is a highly edited version of this.
https://github.com/ChrisFeldmeier/jquery.dataTables.export2Excel.js/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.export2Excel.js

I just need to style the divs inside the tds this structure is inside HTML and is being exported TO EXCEL

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you're exporting HTML for loading *into* Excel, or exporting HTML *from* Excel...

Comment: I'm exporting from an HTML table into an excel spreadsheet

Comment: Whoever wrote the table, however didn't follow the right standards when building it so it's a bit more difficult for me to work with.

Comment: You need to be a little more explicit - it's not realy clear what you mean by "a robust table exporter" for example.  You mention trying some things, but do not show *exactly* what you tried and what the output was (and how it differed from what you want/expect), so it's difficult to know what to suggest.

Comment: Can't really tell but this might be the sort of thing you're looking for (managing block-level elements in a cell) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711034/in-an-html-saved-as-xls-how-to-acheive-altenter-equivalent-in-htmlnew-line-in/40711471#40711471

Comment: Not really sure how to describe it better. I'm building a javascript HTML to Excel exporter. I mean robust because once I figure this out I should be able to turn almost any html table into an excel spreadsheet especially if it's not well coded. I personally would not ever try to put Divs in a table for this exact reason. HTML5 has ways of adjusting this out better, but I don't have the option to change the code, just the javascript.

Comment: If you look at the html and then the output from that html as an excel template what I'm trying to do is style any of the `Test A`s in excel, but in order to do that I have to create an html structure I can import to excel. The code honestly won't help you and not sure if I can share it, but I'm hoping to make it open source with company approval. I will add an example script

Comment: I think this is the reference you're looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155477(office.10).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately that is not what I need.

Comment: What do you *want* that particular output to look like?

Comment: I'm actually just trying to add a border to it. I have added styling to the div but Excel won't accept that upon import

Comment: I only said style it because in the export script I want anyone that uses it to be able to use any style for something like that. I'm mostly trying to write a script to transform an ill formed table into something that at least looks close to the table

Comment: Excel is not a browser - there is a limit to the amount of translation you can expect it to do between HTML and the worksheet.  Excel doesn't know what a div is: likely it just translates any block-level element to a line break, which then ends up putting each "line" into a separate cell.  That was why i suggested you look at the Office HTML reference: that gives you the best chance of being able to control how Excel renders the HTML you're outputting.

Comment: yeah I know it's not a browser. I tried the reference sheet as well before I even tried to comment on here. I'm trying to see what I can nest in there by detecting if it sees a div and then replace the div with something else